# Can't I assign a foreign key to a table that isn't a primary to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'officials_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'resident'

I created a superclass table with two subclasses table that has a relationship with each other. Why did this error occur? Can't I assign a foreign key to a table that isn't a primary to another table?

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    `userid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `emailaddress` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `lastname` varchar(20),
    `firstname` varchar(20),
    `birthday` date,
    `sex` varchar(7) CHECK (sex IN ('Male', 'Female')),
    `address` varchar(100),
    `billingproof` varchar(100),
     PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Resident (
    `residentid` int NOT NULL,
    `userid` int,
    `groupid` int,
    `accntstatus` VARCHAR(13) CHECK (accntstatus IN ('Approved', 'For Approval', 'Disapproved')),
    `residenttype` VARCHAR(40) CHECK (residenttype IN ('Individual Resource', 'Service Provider', 'Individual Resource and Service Provider')),
    `householdid` INT,
    `elected` boolean,
     FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES User(userid)
);  

CREATE TABLE Officials (
    `electedid` int NOT NULL,
    `userid` int,
    `position` varchar(15) CHECK (position IN ('Staff', 'Village Officer')),
    `isSystemAdmin` boolean,
    `startDate` date,
    `endDate` date,
    `residentid` int,
    FOREIGN KEY (residentid) REFERENCES Resident(residentid),
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES User(userid)
);
```

Comment: As your question is specific for mysql, could you also add the tag `mysql`? That will help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL it is not necessary that the referenced key is a primary key, but it must be guaranteed to be unique through an index (see [MySQL documentation on foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys **and referenced keys** so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

This is also clearly indicated in the error message you got:

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. **Missing index** for constraint 'officials_ibfk_1' **in the referenced table 'resident'**

So to solve it, change:

```
`residentid` int NOT NULL,
```

to:

```
`residentid` int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Comment: I have added 'NOT NULL' and `UNIQUE` keyword to all of my foreign keys in my tables but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d2727c316fc775abfa923f698e596436) using MySQL 5.7. What is your version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

> A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that **refers to the PRIMARY KEY** in another table. [source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE Resident (
`residentid` int NOT NULL,
`userid` int,
`groupid` int,
`accntstatus` VARCHAR(13) CHECK (accntstatus IN ('Approved', 'For Approval', 'Disapproved')),
`residenttype` VARCHAR(40) CHECK (residenttype IN ('Individual Resource', 'Service Provider', 'Individual Resource and Service Provider')),
`householdid` INT,
`elected` boolean,
 PRIMARY KEY (residentid),
 FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES User(userid));
```

- You need to make ***residentid*** a primary key, so you can foreign key from ***Officials*** to ***Resident***